# Not able to select into a variable from dual table

Tags: oracle11g

Can anyone tell what is error here. I'm not able to run below statment.

SELECT to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Month') INTO Mon from dual;

Error : ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"

Comment: `INTO <variable>` is for PL/SQL. What are you actually trying to do? How is the variable declared/defined and how will you use it? Or are you just trying to run a query and specify an alias for the column expression?

Answer (score 1):

This will work inside the stored procedure.

If you want to run it as a normal sql query, then remove `INTO` or replace `INTO` to `AS`:

```sql
SELECT to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Month') AS Mon from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query works in PL/SQL:

```sql
DECLARE
  mon VARCHAR2(9);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Month') INTO Mon from dual;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( mon );
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> March
> ```

However, you don't need to use a `SELECT` statement and can do it entirely in PL/SQL (without the context switch to SQL):

```sql
DECLARE
  mon VARCHAR2(9);
BEGIN
  mon := to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Month');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( mon );
END;
/
```

or, even better, by specifying the NLS settings in the query so that it will give the same answers independent of anyone's settings in their session:

```sql
DECLARE
  mon VARCHAR2(9);
BEGIN
  mon := to_char(add_months(sysdate,-1),'Month','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( mon );
END;
/
```

If you want to do it in SQL (and not in a PL/SQL context) then you cannot use `INTO`:

```sql
SELECT to_char(
         add_months(sysdate,-1),
         'Month',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=American'
       ) AS mon
FROM   DUAL
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> | MON       |
> | :-------- |
> | March     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=247c632b5c29dde741cc265ecfe03f3a)*